# What version of ASP.NET supports using Windows AppFabric caching for session management

Tags: asp.net, appfabric

I would like to know the version of ASP.NET supports using Windows AppFabric caching for session management or is it just about using the AppFabric session provider

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3.5 AND  4 support windows app fabric.